# Is there any particular manner to test web socket using jmeter for its efficiency

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

The scenario is that we need to test a broadcast marquee message that uses web socket in the back end i.e. the message is being pushed to the database whenever changed, web socket gets the data from the database & makes it available on the front end.

This message is to be made visible to around 1000 people at the same time.
Is there any way we could test the failures caused while doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The main rule of load testing is simulating real-life application usage as close as possible so you basically need to implement 1000 threads (virtual users)

1. Install [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]
2. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 virtual user
3. Add WebSocket Open Connection sampler and provide your backend connection details there:

   [image]
4. Add WebSocket Single Read Sampler which will be reading the message from the backend

   [image]

   here you might want to use [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) in order to "wait" for the message if it's not immediately available
5. Once you're done it would make sense to use WebSocket Close sampler to terminate the connection

   [image]
6. Request and response data can be visualized using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Once your test runs fine with 1-2 users you can [increase number of threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) to 1000 and run full load test in command-line non-GUI mode

Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/) article for more information on WebSocket test elements configuration and usage